# How do I get through this door (and what's behind it)?

Tags: the-forgotten-city

After beating "The Forgotten City", there was one door I never managed to get through.  It's blocked by a statue that can't (as far as I can tell) be moved.

[image: Statue blocking door]

It's near the start of the level, just off to the left of the main path.

How do I get to the other side, and what's there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the only way to get in that door is to break the Golden Rule so that the statue will move while it's trying to attack you. There is a chest in the room with 4000 denarii.

The same door seems to be pictured/outlined in the link below, detailing its location right after the tavern, to your left.

https://itemlevel.net/the-forgotten-city-how-to-get-the-treasure-behind-the-golden-statue/